# Steam crashes on startup

Tags: steam, macos

A couple days ago I bought my new Mac for work because I use my PC for gaming. When I installed steam today it opened but now it crashes. It says "connecting to network" then says "Steam quit unexpectedly" Usually this would be fine but I need to go on now because I don't have my PC with me. I'm updated to the newest version of OS and I have it startup to my library. Has anyone else had this problem and how do I fix it??

Comment: Can you include your OS version in the question? Is it the newest update? Also, is the Store your default page on startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall the Steam client. That will almost surely fix your issue.